# Scope and lifetime of List

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I have a static List of Products type.When I populate this list from Shopowner class, it works fine, but when I compile Customer.java , the list returns blank set. Why is the populated list not retaining ?

```
class Products {

    String name;
    int itemcode;
    Products(){}
    static List <Products> list = new ArrayList<Products>();
    Products(String name,int itemcode)
      {  
        this.name=name;
        this.itemcode=itemcode;
      }
    public String toString()
    {return (name+""+itemcode);}        
}

class Shopowner {       
  public static void main (String ...at)

{
        Products o = new Products("Shamppo",12);    
        Products.list.add(o);
        Products o1 = new Products("choco",1112);   
        Products.list.add(o1);
           System.out.println(Products.list); //prints fine
}
    }

 class Customer {
                public static void main (String args[])
            {       
           System.out.println(Products.list);   //prints [] 
           }    
}
```

OutPut (when compiling Customer.jav)

```
  []
```

Comment: Re: `Products(String c){c=itemname;}` That statement does nothing. The member `itemname` will still be `null`. What are you trying to do there? Perhaps you meant `this.itemname = c;`?

Comment: Sorry ! that was typo, corrected.

Comment: The code is just a mess. Can you proper format it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See below for part of your code:

```
public static void main (String ...a)
{
Products o= new Products("Chocolate"); 
o.addToList();
Products o1= new Products("Icecream");
o1.addToList();
new Products().showList(); //This line is the culprit
```

You are adding list in Object o and o1 and you are calling showList() on a different object altogether *new Products().showList();*?

**Note:**
It works for static list because it is shared among all the objects of your Product class, which is not the case with non-static list.

Comment: How to retrieve this list from customer class without adding anything in this class. I can create a static block in product class and put these inside it.Any other ideas.

Comment: your above point is not clear, you are considering to make the list as static?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make this list static. Now I have created another class Customer
{
     new Products().showList() //Prints []
}

How to retrieve already populated list here

Comment: then it is pretty easy products.list would return you the list in Customer Class.

Comment: @Malwaregeek Please accept an answer if your query is resolved.

Comment: No its not working, it still prints blank set. I compiled the product class ,list is being populated there but not displaying in customer class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've created a new list by creating a new product and called showList on it. If you want the list of a particular product, then you should call the method on the correct object. Static maintains one variable for every instance, so it works when it's static.

Comment: Static list should retain through out the lifetime of project ?

Comment: @Malwaregeek Yes, that's exactly right. A static object will retain its lifetime through the whole run.

Answer (score 0):

First, *compiling* a class is not going to give you the result you mentioned.  You are not only compiling Customer.java, but you are executing the main method in Customer.

It seems to me that you have 2 main methods, one in Customer, and one in Shopowner.  You expect when you are running Customer#main(), you will see the things populated in Shopowner#main().  However this is simply not rational: If you run Shopowner#main(), it is another process from your another run of Customer#main().  Static variables are not going to carried across different processes.

I believe you should have some basic understanding on programming.  There are lots of design issue in your code that you need to fix, but compared with the problem mentioned above, they are becoming trivial....

Comment: Okay ,if I put the populating list code inside paramaetrized constructor and invoke it from customer class,it should work fine. new Shopowner("Add products");

Or Instead of creating a separate classes for shopowner and customer, I can create a single class retail, using switch statements I can add functionality of adding products as shpowner or buying products as customer.

Comment: so what are you asking in fact?  I am not sure if it is my problem or not... I simply have no idea on what you tried to express.

Comment: make sure you know what you are asking, and ask it in a way that other people can understand.  It is not about beginner or not.  There are lots of beginners that asks well

Comment: Okay :) I was asking about the design issues you were referring to. Can you please elaborate it in your answer.

Comment: 1. Your question is asking for "change in static variable not visible" issue.  If you want to talk on another topic, raise another question.  2. Such design question is subjective, and Stack Overflow is probably not an appropriate place to discuss on this.  Clean your question up and check if it is appropriate to ask in http://codereview.stackexchange.com